# What is the name of chess format in which one player has only pawns, no king?

Tags: chess-variants, online-chess

I remember watching some games on youtube in this weird format but forgot what it's called.
One player has only pawns (lots of them. no other pieces, not even king) and has to achieve mate. Other player has to capture all of opponent's pawns to win the game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is either Horde or the very similar Dunsany's chess: 32 pawns against the regular chess army.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can play Horde chess on lichess.org for free without creating an account.

Comment: Correct, it's Horde chess. Now you have a guide on it too: https://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Guide-Horde-Chess-strategies/dp/B092XPNNVS